# Apache Solr Querying by search term from multiple tables and in all columns

Tags: solr

I am new to Apache Solr and have worked with single table and importing it in Solr to get data using query.

Now I want to do following.

1. query from multiple tables ..... Like if I find by a word, it should return all occurances in multiple tables.
2. Search in all fields of table ....like I query by word in all fields in single table too.

Do I need to create single document by importing data from multiple tables using joins in data-config.xml? And then querying over it?

Any leads and guidance is welcome.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to create single document by importing data from multiple tables using joins in data-config.xml? And then querying over it?

Yes. Solr uses a document model (rather than a relational model) and the general approach is to index a single document with the fields that you need for searching.

From the [Apache Solr guide](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/overview-of-documents-fields-and-schema-design.html#how-solr-sees-the-world):

> Solr’s basic unit of information is a document, which is a set of data
> that describes something. A recipe document would contain the
> ingredients, the instructions, the preparation time, the cooking time,
> the tools needed, and so on. A document about a person, for example,
> might contain the person’s name, biography, favorite color, and shoe
> size. A document about a book could contain the title, author, year of
> publication, number of pages, and so on.

Comment: Thankyou for the guidance. :) 
Basically I want to make my website searchable. so if someone write a word in searchbar,
it should return all occurrences of that word in database with the metadata that is present in  tables we have this word....

Now my concern is, if I join all of my database in one document  and then query over it? Would It take much time to query over it? 

Moreover I was trying to find way to query from all columns of document? I tried by defining field type of multivalued and then copying all fields to this multivaliued, is it best approach? 
TIA